# Есть ли примеры с наречием "овально"?

Tags: морфология, наречия

В этимологическом словаре Петра Червинского и Маргариты Надель-Червинской про слово "овально" сказано так - бывает наречием и прилагательным, имеет формы сравнения - овальнее, овальней.

Посмотрел у Зализника, там тоже е "овально" дается наречие.

Но реальных примеров мне не удалось найти. Может, кому-нибудь из вас попадались примеры с этим словом в качестве наречия.

Comment: Спасибо, что заметили. Исправлю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из Нацкорпуса:

Что касается вырезов, самые модные — круглые, **овально** вытянутые спереди. [И. Андреева. Из копилки моды // «Работница», 1980]

Было что беречь: неширокая кисть с толстыми длинными пальцами, с **овально** подстриженными ногтями в йодистой окантовке. [Людмила Улицкая. Пиковая дама (1995-2000)]

Comment: А какие ещё варианты? Обозначает признак признака, отвечает на вопрос как?

Comment: Это автору надо адресовать. Он такой вопрос задавал.

Comment: Вопрос был в том, что со  мной спорили, что овально - относительное прилагательное. Когда в словаре нашлось наречие, стал искать примеры - не нашел. Потом, после вашего ответа, тоже обратился к Корпусу и нашел еще наречия там.